# Unable to binding radio value onclick funtion for every iteration on ng repeat form

Tags: angularjs

```js
var aaa = angular.module("Module", [])
aaa.controller("Controller", function($scope, $filter, $timeout, $http, jsonFilter) {
$scope.SalaryData = [];
  $scope.addSalaryField = function() {
    $scope.SalaryData.push({});
  }

  $scope.first = function(abc) {
    $scope.salry.abc = $scope.abc;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="Module" data-ng-controller="Controller">
  <form role="form" id="SalaryInfoForm" name="SalaryInfoForm" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate="">
    <div ng-repeat="salry in SalaryData">
      <p>Salary Given</p>
       <div class="tabbable-panel">
     <div class="tabbable-line">
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab_default_1" data-toggle="tab" data-ng-click="first(salry.abc)" style="padding:10px 55px 10px 15px">Yes </a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab_default_2" data-toggle="tab" data-ng-click="first(salry.abc)" style="padding:10px 15px 10px 55px">No </a></li>
   </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
      <input type="radio" name="abc" id="abc"  ng-model="salry.abc" value="Yes">Yes
      <input type="radio" name="abc" id="abc"  ng-model="salry.abc" value="No">No
    </div>
    <a data-ng-click="addSalaryField()">SAVE & ADD MORE</a>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am here repeating div using onclick `addSalaryField()` function. While clicking every iteration of `first()` function in tabpanel the value should be assign to radio ng-model. It's not working. Kindly help us.! we need to fetch value to ng-model on every iteration

Comment: Define your scope variable "SalaryData" in your controller: `$scope.SalaryData = [];`. Then you'll find more to fix for the radio buttons when you click to add more to the array.

Comment: pass the model as a parameter: `first(salry)`. Also why do you need to change it that way? It's a radio, not a checkbox